# Exporting to GIF doesn't work

Tags: export, version-9, gif-format

I cannot export a list of images (or a single image) to GIF format. I use Win10 with Mathematica 9.0. It previously worked on an other device with Win7. I can also export an image to other formats, like PNG or JPG.

`Export["file.gif",image]` produces an output which cannot be opened with anything (Windows Images, Paint, or any browser, ...). `Export["file.png",image]` works well.

Sorry if it's a common problem, but I haven't found an answer here.

An example code:

```
image = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["file1.gif", image]
Export["file2.jpg", image]
```

Comment: I export to gif all the time, on windows 10. But I use V 12.1. No problems (other than it can slow). Can you post complete MWE where it fails? are you exporting frames of images or single image?

Comment: @Nasser I posted an expamle. It is only a single image, but I still cannot open the gif file, while I can the jpg. Is it possible that the problem isn't on Mathetmatica's side?

Comment: it works OK on my end. exported OK, opened image using paint.exe, all ok. So have no idea why it fails for you. May be problem with V 9. I do not have that on my PC now to try it.

Comment: Try wrapping the plot with `Image[...]` and removing the alpha channel, then exporting it.
`image = RemoveAlphaChannel[Image[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]], White]`

Comment: @flinty I tried your suggestion, but the problem remained the same.

Comment: Can you please post the output of this command here:
`Export["test.gif", Image[{{0}}]]; im = ReadList["test.gif", Byte]`

Comment: @flinty This is the output: `{71, 73, 70, 56, 57, 97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33, 254, 52, 67, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 100, 32, 98, 121, 32, 87, 111, 108, 102, 114, 97, 109, 32, 77, 97, 116, 104, 101, 109, 97, 116, 105, 99, 97, 32, 57, 46, 48, 32, 58, 32, 119, 119, 119, 46, 119, 111, 108, 102, 114, 97, 109, 46, 99, 111, 109, 0, 33, 249, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 124, 1, 0, 59}`.

Comment: In those bytes the width and height fields of the GIF89a header are zero which is corrupt. Are you using an empty notebook? Do you have any special init.m setup? Does it work if you explicitly add the size with  `Export["test.gif", Image[{{0}}], ImageSize->1]` ?

Comment: @flinty The nobebook only cointains these test codes. I don't use init.m, and the output is the same with `ImageSize->1`.